# How to position the default loadingroute in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

EmberJS provides a `loadinroute` which can be used to render a spinner etc. while the promise is being processed.

By default it processes under the `{{outlet}}`. I'm wondering if there is a way to position the render to someplace else?

For example in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ixazeb/8/edit I want to position the `loading...` on top of the `App` text.

I've tried to tap into the `renderTemplate` like this:

```
App.LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({ outlet: 'sidebar' });
  }
});
```

and using it in my template like this: `{{outlet sidebar}}` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the target template name to append the loading template, using `into: 'application'`

```
App.LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('loading', {
      outlet: 'loading',
      into: 'application'
    });
  }
});
```

Now it works http://jsbin.com/ixazeb/14/edit